# Change Blazor offline chrome window style

Tags: progressive-web-apps, blazor

Can we change the style of the window that host Blazor offline apps, Like changing title bar color or set an icon or change default window back color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes - in the `manifest.json` - see https://pwa-workshop.js.org/1-manifest/#manifest-fields

example:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "short_name": "myapp",
  "start_url": "./",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#B4ECF9",
  "theme_color": "#F00BAA",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/android-chrome-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/android-chrome-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```